# Error en concatenación SQL, en Python 3

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

es mi primera pregunta, por tanto perdónenme las torpezas.
intento concatenar una variable para una actualización pero me da el siguiente error:

> " WHERE ID=" + variableID.get(),(consultaparametrizada))>
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "+": syntax error

mi código es el siguiente:

```
 cursor.execute("UPDATE USUARIOS SET 
   NOMBRE=?,APELLIDOS=?,DIRECCION+?,PASSWORD=?,COMENTARIOS=?"+
  "WHERE ID=" + variableID.get(),(consultaparametrizada))
```

Comment: `DIRECCION+?,` ese mas si va ahi?

Comment: Buenas, como dice @srJJ, en vez de `DIRECCION+?` no seria `DIRECCION=?`

Comment: Uno piensa que ha revisado bien la sintaxis y mira por donde... 
...Tengo un teclado anglosajón que uso muchas veces con la configuración en Español y estos errores me pasan a menudo..
Gracias...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independientemente del error tipográfico que ya te han señalado en `DIRECCION+?` cuando debería ser `DIRECCION=?`, **evita construir la query con los métodos propios de las cadenas de Python**, ya sea concatenando (lo cual ya es por sí ineficiente dado que son inmutables) o usando métodos de formateo de cadenas como  `str.format`, literales de cadena formateados (`f''`), etc . La principal razón es **por seguridad**, si no eres muy cuidadoso es fácil hacer tu programa susceptible a ataques de inyección de código.

En tu caso, en vez de concatenar la cadena, simplemente parametriza también el valor de `ID`:

```
query = """
UPDATE usuarios
SET nombre=?,
    apellidos=?,
    direccion=?,
    password=?,
    comentarios=?
WHERE id=?"""

cursor.execute(query, (*consultaparametrizada, variableID.get()))
```

Estoy presuponiendo que `consultaparametrizada` en un iterable como una lista o una tupla con el resto de valores que tienes formada previamente. De cualquier forma la idea es pasar una tupla o lista con todos los valores necesarios.

Comment: ¿Es necesario usar `\\` en el inicio del *query*?

Comment: @eyllanesc no es necesario para nada..., el salto de línea en la consulta simplemente se va a ignorar. Es una manía mía seguramente producto de dar ejemplos para Pandas usando`io.StringIO` para emular archivos csv, dónde ese primer salto de línea es una gran diferencia XD. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: Entiendo, suele suceder :-)

Comment: @FJSevilla:
Me gustaría que me aclararas, si eres tan amable,  porque la inmutabilidad vuelve ineficiente a la concatenación. 
La parametrización total, me parece muy elegante, de fácil lectura..  Pero ahora me da otro error... ..ésta vez te copio todo el código.

Comment: Olvida lo anterior, @FJSevilla, funciona todo muy bien, aunque la pregunta que te he hecho sigue estando presente. Una última cosa... ¿Solo se puede dar un voto en cada pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Si despues de comentarios no dejas un espacio al concatenar  te quedaria esto:

```
COMENTARIOS=?WHERE
```

Ademas en DIRECCION debes poner = en vez de +.

```
DIRECCION=?
```

Deberia de quedar asi:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE USUARIOS SET 
           NOMBRE=?,APELLIDOS=?,DIRECCION+?,PASSWORD=?,COMENTARIOS=? "+
          "WHERE ID=" + variableID.get(),(consultaparametrizada))
```